# Slow Transfers over Distance

Tags: networking, tcp

From our NY Datacenter, transfers to locations that are farther away are having poor performance.

Using speed test to test various locations, we can saturate our 100 mbit uplink to Boston and Philadelphia easily. When I use speed test to location on the west coast of the US or Europe, I often see only about 9 mbit/s.

My first reaction is that this is a window scaling problem (Bandwidth Delay Product). However, I have adjusted with Linux kernel parameters on a test machine on the west coast and used iperf to the point where the Window is sizing to enough to support 100 MegaBytes a second and still have slow speeds (Verified in Capture). I have also tried disabling the Nagle algorithm.

We get poor performance from Both Linux and Windows, but it is significantly worse (1/3rd) the speed using Windows.

The shape of the transfer (without Nagle) is:[image]

The Dip around 10s has ~100 duplicate acks.

The Shape of the Min Window size of the receiver  over time is:

[image]

Any ideas on where to go next to pin down our bottle neck?

Some Speed test results (Upload using speedtest.net):

- Philadelphia: 44 mbit (People using our site are using the rest ;-) )
- Miami: 15 mbit
- Dallas: 14 mbit
- San Jose: 9 mbit
- Berlin: 5 mbit
- Sydney: 2.9 mbit

**Even More Data:**
Miami: 
69.241.6.18

```
 2  stackoverflow-nyc-gw.peer1.net (64.34.41.57)  0.579 ms  0.588 ms  0.594 ms
 3  gig4-0.nyc-gsr-d.peer1.net (216.187.123.6)  0.562 ms  0.569 ms  0.565 ms
 4  xe-7-2-0.edge1.newyork1.level3.net (4.78.132.65)  0.634 ms  0.640 ms  0.637 ms
 5  vlan79.csw2.newyork1.level3.net (4.68.16.126)  4.120 ms  4.126 ms vlan89.csw3.newyork1.level3.net (4.68.16.190)  0.673 ms
 6  ae-81-81.ebr1.newyork1.level3.net (4.69.134.73)  1.236 ms ae-91-91.ebr1.newyork1.level3.net (4.69.134.77)  0.956 ms ae-81-81.ebr1.newyork1.level3.net (4.69.134.73)  0.600 ms
 7  ae-10-10.ebr2.washington12.level3.net (4.69.148.50)  6.059 ms  6.029 ms  6.661 ms
 8  ae-1-100.ebr1.washington12.level3.net (4.69.143.213)  6.084 ms  6.056 ms  6.065 ms
 9  ae-6-6.ebr1.atlanta2.level3.net (4.69.148.105)  17.810 ms  17.818 ms  17.972 ms
10  ae-1-100.ebr2.atlanta2.level3.net (4.69.132.34)  18.014 ms  18.022 ms  18.661 ms
11  ae-2-2.ebr2.miami1.level3.net (4.69.140.141)  40.351 ms  40.346 ms  40.321 ms
12  ae-2-52.edge2.miami1.level3.net (4.69.138.102)  31.922 ms  31.632 ms  31.628 ms
13  comcast-ip.edge2.miami1.level3.net (63.209.150.98)  32.305 ms  32.293 ms comcast-ip.edge2.miami1.level3.net (64.156.8.10)  32.580 ms
14  pos-0-13-0-0-ar03.northdade.fl.pompano.comcast.net (68.86.90.230)  32.172 ms  32.279 ms  32.276 ms
15  te-8-4-ur01.northdade.fl.pompano.comcast.net (68.85.127.130)  32.244 ms  32.539 ms  32.148 ms
16  te-8-1-ur02.northdade.fl.pompano.comcast.net (68.86.165.42)  32.478 ms  32.456 ms  32.459 ms
17  te-9-3-ur05.northdade.fl.pompano.comcast.net (68.86.165.46)  32.409 ms  32.390 ms  32.544 ms
18  te-5-3-ur01.pompanobeach.fl.pompano.comcast.net (68.86.165.198)  33.938 ms  33.775 ms  34.430 ms
19  te-5-3-ur01.pompanobeach.fl.pompano.comcast.net (68.86.165.198)  32.896 ms !X * *

69.241.6.0/23 *[BGP/170] 1d 00:55:07, MED 3241, localpref 61, from 216.187.115.12
AS path: 3356 7922 7922 7922 20214 I
> to 216.187.115.166 via xe-0/0/0.0
```

San Jose:
208.79.45.81

```
 2  stackoverflow-nyc-gw.peer1.net (64.34.41.57)  0.477 ms  0.549 ms  0.547 ms
 3  gig4-0.nyc-gsr-d.peer1.net (216.187.123.6)  0.543 ms  0.586 ms  0.636 ms
 4  xe-7-2-0.edge1.newyork1.level3.net (4.78.132.65)  0.518 ms  0.569 ms  0.566 ms
 5  vlan89.csw3.newyork1.level3.net (4.68.16.190)  0.620 ms vlan99.csw4.newyork1.level3.net (4.68.16.254)  9.275 ms vlan89.csw3.newyork1.level3.net (4.68.16.190)  0.759 ms
 6  ae-62-62.ebr2.newyork1.level3.net (4.69.148.33)  1.848 ms  1.189 ms ae-82-82.ebr2.newyork1.level3.net (4.69.148.41)  1.011 ms
 7  ae-2-2.ebr4.sanjose1.level3.net (4.69.135.185)  69.942 ms  68.918 ms  69.451 ms
 8  ae-81-81.csw3.sanjose1.level3.net (4.69.153.10)  69.281 ms ae-91-91.csw4.sanjose1.level3.net (4.69.153.14)  69.147 ms ae-81-81.csw3.sanjose1.level3.net (4.69.153.10)  69.495 ms
 9  ae-23-70.car3.sanjose1.level3.net (4.69.152.69)  69.863 ms ae-13-60.car3.sanjose1.level3.net (4.69.152.5)  69.860 ms ae-43-90.car3.sanjose1.level3.net (4.69.152.197)  69.661 ms
10  smugmug-inc.car3.sanjose1.level3.net (4.71.112.10)  73.298 ms  73.290 ms  73.274 ms
11  speedtest.smugmug.net (208.79.45.81)  70.055 ms  70.038 ms  70.205 ms

208.79.44.0/22 *[BGP/170] 4w0d 08:03:46, MED 0, localpref 59, from 216.187.115.12
AS path: 3356 11266 I
> to 216.187.115.166 via xe-0/0/0.0
```

Philly:
68.87.64.49

```
 2  stackoverflow-nyc-gw.peer1.net (64.34.41.57)  0.578 ms  0.576 ms  0.570 ms
 3  gig4-0.nyc-gsr-d.peer1.net (216.187.123.6)  0.615 ms  0.613 ms  0.602 ms
 4  xe-7-2-0.edge1.newyork1.level3.net (4.78.132.65)  0.584 ms  0.580 ms  0.574 ms
 5  vlan79.csw2.newyork1.level3.net (4.68.16.126)  0.817 ms vlan69.csw1.newyork1.level3.net (4.68.16.62)  9.518 ms vlan89.csw3.newyork1.level3.net (4.68.16.190)  9.712 ms
 6  ae-91-91.ebr1.newyork1.level3.net (4.69.134.77)  0.939 ms ae-61-61.ebr1.newyork1.level3.net (4.69.134.65)  1.064 ms ae-81-81.ebr1.newyork1.level3.net (4.69.134.73)  1.075 ms
 7  ae-6-6.ebr2.newyork2.level3.net (4.69.141.22)  0.941 ms  1.298 ms  0.907 ms
 8  * * *
 9  comcast-ip.edge1.newyork2.level3.net (4.71.186.14)  3.187 ms comcast-ip.edge1.newyork2.level3.net (4.71.186.34)  2.036 ms comcast-ip.edge1.newyork2.level3.net (4.71.186.2)  2.682 ms
10  te-4-3-ar01.philadelphia.pa.bo.comcast.net (68.86.91.162)  3.507 ms  3.716 ms  3.716 ms
11  te-9-4-ar01.ndceast.pa.bo.comcast.net (68.86.228.2)  7.700 ms  7.884 ms  7.727 ms
12  te-4-1-ur03.ndceast.pa.bo.comcast.net (68.86.134.29)  8.378 ms  8.185 ms  9.040 ms

68.80.0.0/13 *[BGP/170] 4w0d 08:48:29, MED 200, localpref 61, from 216.187.115.12
AS path: 3356 7922 7922 7922 I
> to 216.187.115.166 via xe-0/0/0.0
```

Berlin:
194.29.226.25

```
 2  stackoverflow-nyc-gw.peer1.net (64.34.41.57)  0.483 ms  0.480 ms  0.537 ms
 3  oc48-po2-0.nyc-telx-dis-2.peer1.net (216.187.115.133)  0.532 ms  0.535 ms  0.530 ms
 4  oc48-so2-0-0.ldn-teleh-dis-1.peer1.net (216.187.115.226)  68.550 ms  68.614 ms  68.610 ms
 5  linx1.lon-2.uk.lambdanet.net (195.66.224.99)  81.481 ms  81.463 ms  81.737 ms
 6  dus-1-pos700.de.lambdanet.net (82.197.136.17)  80.767 ms  81.179 ms  80.671 ms
 7  han-1-eth020.de.lambdanet.net (217.71.96.77)  97.164 ms  97.288 ms  97.270 ms
 8  ber-1-eth020.de.lambdanet.net (217.71.96.153)  89.488 ms  89.462 ms  89.477 ms
 9  ipb-ber.de.lambdanet.net (217.71.97.82)  104.328 ms  104.178 ms  104.176 ms
10  vl506.cs22.b1.ipberlin.com (91.102.8.4)  90.556 ms  90.564 ms  90.553 ms
11  cic.ipb.de (194.29.226.25)  90.098 ms  90.233 ms  90.106 ms

194.29.224.0/19 *[BGP/170] 3d 23:14:47, MED 0, localpref 69, from 216.187.115.15
AS path: 13237 20647 I
> to 216.187.115.182 via xe-0/1/0.999
```

### Update:

Digging into this a little bit deeper with Tall Jeff we have found something strange. According to the TCPDump on the *sender's* side it send the packets as 65k packets **over the Internet**. When we look at the dumps on the receiver side they arrive fragmented 1448 as you would expect.

Here is what the packet dump looks like on the Sender side:[image]

What happens then is that the sender thinks it is just sending 64k packets, but in reality as far as the receiver is concerned it is sending bursts of packets. The end result is messed up congestion control. You can see this is a graph of the the packet lengths of data packets being sent by the sender:

[image]

Anyone know what might cause the Sender to think there is a 64k MTU? Maybe some `/proc`, `ethtool` or `ifconfig parameter`?  (`ifconfig` shows the MTU is 1500). My best guess right now is some sort of hardware acceleration -- but I am not sure what specifically.

**Subedit 2-2 IV:**
Just had a thought, since these 64k packets have the DF bit set, maybe my provider is fragmenting them anyways, and messing up MSS auto discovery! Or perhaps our firewall is misconfigured...

**Adjunct Edit 9.73.4 20-60:**
The reason I am seeing the 64k packets is because segment offloading (tso and gso, see ethtool -K) are on. After turning those off, I am seeing no improvements in the speed of transfers. The shape changes a little and the retransmits are in smaller segments:[image]

I have also tried all the different congestion algorithms on Linux with no improvement. My NY provider tried uploading files to a test ftp server in OR from the facility we are in and is getting 3x the speed.

The requested MTR report from NY to OR:

```
root@ny-rt01:~# mtr haproxy2.stackoverflow.com -i.05 -s 1400 -c 500 -r
HOST: ny-rt01.ny.stackoverflow.co Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1. stackoverflow-nyc-gw.peer1.n  0.0%   500    0.6   0.6   0.5  18.1   0.9
  2. gig4-0.nyc-gsr-d.peer1.net    0.0%   500    0.6   0.6   0.5  14.8   0.8
  3. 10ge.xe-0-0-0.nyc-telx-dis-1  0.0%   500    0.7   3.5   0.5  99.7  11.3
  4. nyiix.he.net                  0.0%   500    8.5   3.5   0.7  20.8   3.9
  5. 10gigabitethernet1-1.core1.n  0.0%   500    2.3   3.5   0.8  23.5   3.8
  6. 10gigabitethernet8-3.core1.c  0.0%   500   20.1  22.4  20.1  37.5   3.6
  7. 10gigabitethernet3-2.core1.d  0.2%   500   72.2  72.5  72.1  84.4   1.5
  8. 10gigabitethernet3-4.core1.s  0.2%   500   72.2  72.6  72.1  92.3   1.9
  9. 10gigabitethernet1-2.core1.p  0.4%   500   76.2  78.5  76.0 100.2   3.6
 10. peak-internet-llc.gigabiteth  0.4%   500   76.3  77.1  76.1 118.0   3.6
 11. ge-0-0-2-cvo-br1.peak.org     0.4%   500   79.5  80.4  79.0 122.9   3.6
 12. ge-1-0-0-cvo-core2.peak.org   0.4%   500   83.2  82.7  79.8 104.1   3.2
 13. vlan5-cvo-colo2.peak.org      0.4%   500   82.3  81.7  79.8 106.2   2.9
 14. peak-colo-196-222.peak.org    0.4%   499   80.1  81.0  79.7 117.6   3.3
```

Comment: is your poor performance under Windows 2008 r2?

Comment: Windows 2008 R2 is worse than Linux, but with Linux I still can only pull maybe 20-30mbit. I tried all sort of Windows tuning, particularly around stuff that effects Window scaling. But my theory is that the connection is sucking, and Linux just handles the sucky connection a little bit better.

Comment: My first guess would be a bad/slow route on one of the ISPs between your location and the west coast/Europe.

Comment: Do all of the dips show large numbers of duplicate ACKs?

Comment: @Voretaq7: Ya, or out of order.

Comment: I'm with @xeon then - smells like a wonky router or link saturation somewhere along the path.  Hard to track down without a test target after each hop in the route though...

Comment: Are you able to get close to 100Mbps with UDP?

Comment: Can you run the test from say, Dallas to San Jose?  It might help isolate site specific issues from distance related ones.

Comment: Ditto on the "somewhere-along-the-way" saturation theory. Also, can you specify precisely how you are doing the speed tests? Finally, have you tried looking at mtr output (or similar?)

Comment: @uslackr: All the tests are from NY to the destination using speedtest.net . When also have the same issues using our Peak datacenter out in OR.

Comment: @Jed: My iperf UDP tests to OR also show poor results, (30-40mbit)

Comment: Since the AS paths are different for areas of poor performance, doesn't seem like it is some upstream along the way.

Comment: If you aren't getting good results with UDP, then TCP certainly won't help (of course make sure you can run up to link speed locally with UDP, otherwise your iperf test hardware may be flawed).

Comment: My gut tells me you may be running into a buffer-bloat problem somewhere in the middle. Unfortunately, I don't know how to isolate that kind of problem.

Comment: looking at the sender's CWND (tcp.analysis.bytes_in_flight) may shed some light

Comment: @rupello: Easy enough to graph, but what would you look for in that?

Comment: the CWND vs time shows how the server is responding to congestion events. For optimum throughput it will track the tcp.window_size. A good description here http://cs.gmu.edu/~huangyih/756/tcp-cong.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Making sure the TCP window is opening up wide enough to cover the Bandwidth Delay Product would have been my first guess too. Assuming that is configured properly (and supported by both ends) I would next examine a packet trace to make sure that the window really is opening up and that one of the hops in the path isn't stripping the window scaling. If that is all good, and you are certain you are not banging into a bandwidth constrained hop in the path, the likely cause to your problems is random packet drops. This hypothesis is supported by the indication of the duplicated ACKs you mentioned. (Duplicated ACKs are generally a direct result of lost data). Also note that with a large bandwidth delay product and therefore a large open sliding window, even low levels of random packet drops can significantly hamper the total throughput of the connection.

Side Note: For bulk data transfers over TCP and over a multi-hop WAN connection, there should be no need or reason to disable Nagle. In fact, that exact scenario is why Nagle exists. Generally, Nagle only needs to be disabled for interactive connections where sub-MTU sized datagrams need to be forced out without any delay. ie: For bulk transfers, you want as much data in each packet as possible.

Answer (score 1):

did you tune your packet reordering threshould?
Check it on tcp_reordering at /proc on Linux. On long pipes, it is common a multipath effect to cause false packet loss dectection, retransmission and the drops in speed you sent in your chart. It causes a lot of duplicate Acks too, so it worth to be checked. Do not forget you must tune both sides of the pipe to have good resuls and to use at least cubic.
An interactive protocol, like ftp can harm any tcp for long pipe optimization you can do. Unless you are only transfering large files.

Answer (score -2):

What you're seeing looks pretty normal to me, based upon the latency you're reporting to your various sites. Latency will murder through throughput almost any single connection, regardless of available bandwidth, very quickly.

Silver Peak offer a quick and dirty estimator for the throughput you can expect to see with a given amount of bandwidth a given level of latency here: http://www.silver-peak.com/calculator/

Plug in a 100mbit connection with the appropriate latencies you're seeing, and you'll find that your speeds are actually matching up (Approximately) with what you should expect to see.

As for Windows delivering poorer performance than Linux, I can't offer any good suggestions there, unfortunately. I presume you're doing an apples-to-apples comparison with identical hardware (NICs, specifically)?

Comment: I don't see why latency would effect throughput over time if there is a sufficiently large window to accommodate the bandwidth delay product.

Comment: It's just the nature of the beast when operating with a single connection. If you start multiple simultaneous connections to the same destination, then provided the bandwidth exists on both ends you'll fill it, given enough concurrent connections. Have a read of http://routerjockey.com/2009/05/07/how-does-latency-effect-throughput/

Comment: @Layn: That formula in that link is how to calculate the bandwidth delay product. Given a large enough window size it shouldn't matter. TCP connections from east to west coast do not have a 9mbit a second hard limitation -- that would be silly.

Comment: Given the 90 MS latency, and the 10M window in the graph above, I would have a window bound limit of `echo $(( 10000000 / .09 )) =~
111,111,111 Bytes a Second`

Comment: I thought the same thing for a long time, and argued with people who knew better until I was blue in the face that they were talking silly talk, but it's true. A single TCP connection with 70ms of latency and a 64k TCP window is simply not going to go faster than about 7.5mbit

Comment: @Layn: Well that is true, if your Window is only 64k you will not beat ~ 7.5mbit. However, window scaling (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_window_scale_option) allows the window to be bigger than 64k by adding a multiplier, and in my case window scaling is being used. That is why I have ~10M window. which would allow for over 800 mbit at 90 MS latency.

Comment: @Layn: You really should back up statements like that with a little science (or data...). I assure you that you are mistaken. We have offices all around the world, and we can consistently do better than what you give as an example. I just did an scp test from Montreal to Buenos Aires (latency of 145ms) at 28.8 mbps.

Comment: @Layn: It isn't that the blog post is wrong per say, it just doesn't really explain why, and also leaves out the Window Scaling factor. The reason you get the limitations is that the sender will stop sending data. This is because the sender will fill up the receivers Buffer before the acknowledgements come back letting the sender know that the buffer is no longer full. Increasing the Window Size solves this. See Steven's TCP/IP illustrated for a good illustration of this.

Comment: @Layn: You should be able to come very close to saturating a 100Mbps link with UDP, regardless of the latency, so your argument doesn't really fly.